# Is there a way to modify the schedule of an AWS Glue Trigger incorporated into an AWS Glue Workflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

I have created an AWS Glue Trigger as part of the AWS Glue Workflow that runs on a periodic basis. I have successfully set the periodic schedule via the trigger with no problems, but now I need to adjust the schedule. Is there a way for me to directly edit the schedule of the trigger without recreating the entire AWS Glue Workflow?

I tried modifying it directly from the AWS Glue Trigger Console:

[image]

[image]

But I can't get it done since the console requires me to choose a glue job that will get executed by the trigger  which is not  applicable to my case  since the trigger should initiate a crawler instead of a glue job.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question for others' reference:

Currently, there is no way to edit it directly using the AWS Glue Console. But I was able to accomplish it without recreating the entire Glue Workflow by leveraging the aws-cli for glue:

```
aws glue update-trigger --name "us_im_bol-cl-t0-prod-tg" --cli-input-json '{"TriggerUpdate":{"Name":"us_im_bol-cl-t0-prod-tg","Schedule":"cron(0 14 * * ? *)","Actions":[{"CrawlerName":"us_im_bol-t0-prod-cl"}]}}'
```

Just update the cron rule for the "Schedule" property.